# Importação com problema de .csv em php

Tags: php

Estou querendo importar dados *.csv* para meu banco de dados.
O problema que estou tendo, é o seguinte, são "conjuntos" de dados (`data`, `valor`, `descrição`), por linha, sendo que na tela está sendo exibido um abaixo do outro.

[image: Como está aparecendo os dados]

Meu PHP:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="arquivo">
<input type="submit" name="pega" value="pega">
</form>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['pega'])) {

include_once("PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php");

$uploadDir = "uploadFile/";

$uploadfile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Arquivo pego com sucesso";
    echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "Não foi possível pegar arquivo";
    echo "<br>";
}

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($uploadfile);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$csvFileName = str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $uploadfile);
$objWriter->save($csvFileName);
if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
 }

 $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
 $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("uploadfile");

 $colunas  = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
 $totalColunas = PHPExcel_Cell::columnByIndexFromString($colunas);

 $totalLinhas = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighetRows();

 echo "<table border='1'>";

 for ($linha=1; $linha <= $totalLinhas; $linha++) { 

    echo "<tr>";

    for ($coluna=0; $coluna <= $totalColunas; $coluna++) { 

        if ($linha == 1) {
            echo "<th>".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellColumnAndRow($coluna,$linha)->getValue());
        }else{
            echo "<th>".utf8_decode($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellColumnAndRow($coluna,$linha)->getValue());
        }

    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Qual problema você está tendo? Para ler ou para imprimir o arquivo?

Comment: Imprimir os dados na tela... Pois com eles "organizados", eu quero jogá-los num BD.

Comment: É um csv ou uma planilha do excel?

Comment: É uma planilha Excel, mas já estou fazendo a conversão de .xlsx para .csv, no php.

Comment: Alguma ideia @rodrigoRigotti e @rray?

Comment: Acho que a parte do csv está certo, você notou quem um `<br>` ali -> `echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";`, joga o `<br>` depois do for, veja se é o resultado esperado.

Comment: Perfeito @rray, ajudou.
Valeu.